# PYTHON: loop throug xml files

Tags: python, xml

i have nearly 200 xml files in folder XML:

```
file1.xml
file2.xml
file3.xml
.
.
.
```

I'd like to loop my function to each on of these files and save all results in one txt file ('a').

My function:

```
def convert():
    API_KEY = 'XXX'
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'} # set what your server accepts

    filesXML = {'file': open('file1.xml', 'rb')}

    res = requests.post(API_KEY, files=filesXML)
    print(res.text)


    file = open('resp.xml', 'w')
    file.write(res.text)
    file.close()
convert()
```

Here i have to parse my resp.xml to add specific values like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Task>
    <Date>2020-06-24</Date>
    <Time>10:40</Time>
    <Main>
        <Type>Car</Type>
        <Task1>Something</Task1>
        <Task2>Something</Task2>
        <Task3>Something</Task3>
        <Task4>Something</Task4>
        <Task5>RESULT</Task5>
        <Task6>1</Task6>
        <Task7>103</Task7>
        <Bill>
            <Type>$</Type>
            <Amount>100</Amount>
        </Bill>
        <Handball>false</Handball>
        <Football>false</Football>
        <Book>false</Book>
    </Main>
</Task>
```

My txt file should be:

```
filename=1,Task7=103,Type=$,Amount=100
filename=2,.....
filename=3,...
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to list all files in a directory.
For this you can use the following code:

```
import os
files = os.listdir(path = "C:/") # Change the path according to your needs
```

This will list all the files kept in the C:/ folder (Or whatever folder you choose) in a list variable `files`
you can get all file names using:

```
for file in files:
    print(file)
```

To use it in your case, you should change your `convert()` function a bit.

```
def convert(xFile):   # Added a xFile parameter 
    API_KEY = 'XXX'
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'}

    filesXML = {'file': open(xFile, 'rb')}    # Changed filename to xFile

    res = requests.post(API_KEY, files=filesXML)
    print(res.text)


    file = open('resp.xml', 'w')
    file.write(res.text)
    file.close()
```

Then you can use it like:

```
for file in files:
    convert(file)
```

**Point to be noted:  The given directory should only contain the xml files, if any other file/folder is found it wil try to use the `convert()` function on those files too!**

Comment: can you please specify what do you want to do with those xml files? I could not understand... Did you want to read the value of a specific tag like `Task7`or `Type` or what?

Comment: @m1711 please specify what you want to do so that i can complete the answer

Comment: thank yor for your time. You already said the solution but i didn't understand it at the first time but i understand it now. Just forget my second question :)